# FOP transformation containing HTML reponse in XML

Tags: html, xml, pdf, apache-fop

I am currently working on one functionality where I have to convert Xml response to PDF using Apache FOP Library.

But currently what is happening that XML response contains some HTML data too like following

```
<SampleResults type="result" mediaType="html"><Text><![CDATA[<p style="text-align: justify; line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 12pt;"><strong><u><span style="color: black;"><span style="font-family: times new roman,serif;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">ABC DEF</span></span></span></u></strong></p>

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: currentColor; width: 667px; border-collapse: collapse;" width="667">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background: rgb(223, 223, 223); padding: 0cm 5.4pt; border: 1pt solid black; width: 334px;">
            <p align="center" style="text-align: center; line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><strong><span style="color: black;"><span style="font-family: times new roman,serif;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">SERVICE&nbsp;</span></span></span></strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="background: rgb(223, 223, 223); border-width: 1pt 1pt 1pt medium; border-style: solid solid solid none; border-color: black black black currentColor; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; width: 334px;">
            <p align="center" style="text-align: center; line-height: normal; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><strong><span style="color: black;"><span style="font-family: times new roman,serif;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">STATUS&nbsp;</span></span></span></strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
]]></Text></SampleResults>
```

I have used the following xslt for the above to show

```
<xsl:template match="t:SampleResults" name="SampleResultsSearch">
        <search>
            <result>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="t:SampleResults/t:Text"/>
            </result>
        </search>
</xsl:template>
```

But right now what is happening that this is showing as a text in the PDF like in following screenshot

[image]

I want that this HTML tag should be properly understood by FOP so that this can be rendered properly in PDF hence is there any mechanism to do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The stuff between `<![CDATA[` and `]]` is understood as text and not as HTML. Before submitting this to FOP, one way of doing it is to remove the head of your XML file up to `<![CDATA[` included and to remove the tail of the same XML file starting from and including `]]`. After that, you will have to code an XSLT procedure matching each HTML tag to transform it into an equivalent input for FOP. `<table>` will become `<fo:table>` with other attributes, `<tr>` will become `<fo:table-row>` also with different attributes. As far as I know, there are no XSLT libraries where this is done by default.

Comment: @PierreFrançois, I think this will not be feasible solution to convert each HTML tag into an equivalent input for FOP as there are many tags present in HTML. Please let me if there is any solution

Comment: HTML and FOP are different languages, both based on XML. The only solution is to find a translator from HTML into FOP. If it doesn't exist, you will have to code a bunch of XSLT transformations. Let us hope somebody else already coded it.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at this: they already did a big part of the job: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/